# bootstrap v3: creating two different "rows" for mobile vs. desktop view ports

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My team is performing some greenfield work and are adopting the bootstrap css framework.

So the question is we are having difficulties in making some elements size right. One of the developers decided to make two rows, one is visible when on mobile and the other when on desktop.

```
<div class="row hidden-sm hidden-xs">
... code for desktop
</div>

<div class="row hidden-lg hidden-md">
... code for mobile
</div>
```

This "feels" wrong and seems that it will increase risk for missing things later and complicates testing for when future changes are required. Additionally, it brings logic into the "view" (we are following the MVC principles).

Does the code snippet above follow best practices AND/OR is this perfectly valid way to code this?

Comment: The code snippet above is demonstrating what is being done for one row; this is being repeated for a total of 3 rows so there is essentially 6 rows being developed - 3 for mobile (non desktop) and 3 for desktops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's valid, but it really depends on the specific layout you're trying to have for each (mobile and desktop). Normally the [responsive utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) are used as a "last resort" since they do require duplicate markup.

From the Bootstrap docs..

> "Try to use these on a limited basis and avoid creating entirely different versions of the same site. Instead, use them to complement each device's presentation."

First try other responsive grid options that Bootstrap offers such as using different grid sizes/breakpoints, column wrapping, nesting, ordering etc..

For example, [here's how you can create one version for both desktop and mobile](http://www.codeply.com/go/5Vm0SH6SDn). This uses multiple grid sizes/breakpoints and column ordering (push-pull).

Comment: As a last resort? Interesting. We've been going at this backwards then.

Comment: Sometimes there are cases where using the responsive utilities (`hidden-*`, `visible-*`) are necessary.

Comment: I **knew** I read that quote somewhere! Thanks. This answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it should be done using cols. I am not sure if it fits to that what you need to put into the row but I've made a 
[little pen](http://codepen.io/dominikdosoudil/pen/eZyReX) to show what I mean.
Bootstrap has xs, sm, md and lg cols. XS is something like smartphone as well as SM, MD are tablets and smaller notebooks and LG are regular monitors. (More or less)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    Content-div
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    Right-side-div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not quite the effect we are looking for but thank you for taking the effort to explain your answer.